# scala sequential post using for comprehension without await

Tags: scala, post, for-loop, spray

Im new to scala and am using spray to post a request to a server. Apologies in advance if this question is somewhat out there. I'd really appreciate if anyone could tell me how to accomplish this or what Im doing incorrectly. What I'd like to do is:

1. Post a request and get back a Future[HttpResponse]
2. Without using Await (because I don't want to block threads), check the response code
3. If it has a status code > 400 then alter the data and repost the data and return the Future[HttpResponse], without doing anything further.
4. If the status code from step 2 is good then return the Future[HttpResponse] from step 2.

This is what I have so far, which doesn't appear to give me the response if the status code was good, however does its job on the server. If I retry the same request, I get the result of the first showing up i.e a 404, whereas I expect the first to return a 404 and the second to fixup the data and resend the request and get that future response instead.

```
def post(headers:HttpHeader, data:HttpEntity): Future[HttpResponse] = {
   ...
}

def secondPost(headers:HttpHeader, data:HttpEntity): Future[HttpResponse] = {
 // fix up  data and repost
 post(newHeaders, newData)
}

for{
  first <- post(headers, data)
  if first.status.intValue > 400
  second < secondPost(headers, data)
} yield {
  if (first.status.intvalue > 400) second else first
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it with flat map

```
post(headers, data) flatMap {
 case response     // first failed, try second requests
    if response.status.intValue > 400 => 
      secondPost(headers, data)

 case response => // first one was good, just return it
      Future.successfull(response)
}
```

Comment: Hi Eugene. Worked like a charm mate :) Appreciate it